# Multiple Paths in Single SMB Share

Tags: samba, smb

I like to make a read only share for a user whom has access to several root folders in my fileserver. I don't want to create a bunch of shares for each folder, can I somehow add multiple paths in smb.conf?

Eg:

```
path=/folder1, /folder2
```

Edit: Without using Symlinks. I understand the Unix FS, but don't want to clutter things up with Symlink, if I have to, I will, but I'd prefer to use path= as its seems simpler/better.

Comment: Look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-do-you-make-samba-follow-symlink-outside-the-shared-path

Comment: I'm not looking to use symlinks, I considered it, but I'd rather create separate SMB shares vs symlinks.

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#PATH) is pretty clear: `path` points to "a directory", with no mention of more than one. Making a directory with a few symlinks is likely easier for future management of the share anyways, as you don't have to always edit and reload the configuration file.

Comment: @ErikF I believe you are correct, so the answer to my question is NO, use symlinks and follow symlinks = yes. You can write up an Answer if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#PATH) is pretty clear:

> **path (S)**
>
> This parameter specifies a directory to which the user of the service
>   is to be given access. [...]

The share path points to "a directory", with no mention of more than one. I can think of several reasons for this: first, it's in keeping with how Unix treats filesystems in general (for example, NFS shares behave the same way); and second, it's difficult to come up with a good way to merge directories in general without potential filename collisions.

Making a share that points to a directory with a few symlinks is likely easier for future management of the share anyways, as you don't have to always edit and reload the configuration file.

Comment: It just seems a simple option to add comma separated paths, infact, I noticed `(S)`, What would that be for? But, I suspect this is correct regardless.

Comment: (S) means that the directive is for shares only; (G) means it's a `[global]` directive.