# Accessing a samba share, a symlink, on host, to a folder, appears as an empty folder

Tags: debian, symlink, samba, samba4

In a server, with Debian 10 and Samba 4.9, there are 2 HDs with this mount points:

```
/hd1
/hd2
```

In /hd1 there is a folder that is Samba shared.

```
/hd1/share
```

Inside the share I decide to move a folder to /hd2

```
/hd2/afolder
```

and create a symlink to it

```
ln -s /hd2/bigfolder /hd1/share/bigfolder
```

At server

```
ls /hd1/share/bigfolder
```

shows

```
file1
file2
```

Accessing the share from a client (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
smb://server/share/bigfolder
```

it seams like an empty folder.

I need to see and work in the files (file1 and file2)

Comment: Check is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-do-you-make-samba-follow-symlink-outside-the-shared-path helps.

Comment: Rather than adding the solution to the question itself, you may post it as a proper answer. You may later accept your own answer if nobody else posts a better one. Accepting an answer marks the issue as solved. I have rolled back your most recent edit.

Comment: Do you, who commented, think it would be better to delete this question?

Comment: No, don't delete but leave it: your question will become a signpost to another question...  **0:-)**@AnselmoBlancoDominguez

Comment: @Kusalananda, accepted tip.

Comment: @Fabby, accepted tip.
Thanks to all.

Comment: There!  You're a 21 rep user already. **0:-)**  Also don't forget to "accept" your own answer as some people might not click on the link and only read yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using the following settings as mentioned [here already](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-do-you-make-samba-follow-symlink-outside-the-shared-path).

In the "global" section:

```
allow insecure wide links = yes
```

In the Share section in question:

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```